# Changing from String to Array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm building an app to store records in LocalStorage.

Each record is an object in an array, and each record contains multiple objects. The object looks like this:

```
$scope.recordlist.push(
            {
                date: $scope.dateJson, 
                time: $scope.time, 
                car: $scope.carList.code, 
                driver: $scope.driverList.name,
                from: $scope.locationList.place,
                destination: $scope.locationList2.place, 
                pax: $scope.paxList,
                comment: '',
                commenttime: '',
                arrival: '',
                inserted: '',
                cancelled:'',
                duration:''
            }
        );
```

Right now, **comment** and **commenttime** are strings. 
I create and edit them like this from the front-end:

```
<div class="col-md-1 msf-button">

  <button class="btn-primary" 
          ng-init="inserted = true"  
          ng-click="editItem = !editItem" 
          ng-show="!record.arrival && !record.cancelled && !editItem">
               <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </button>

  <button class="btn-success" 
          ng-click="commentTime(record); editItem = !editItem" 
          ng-show="!record.arrival && editItem && !record.cancelled">
               <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
  </button>

</div>

<div class="row msf-comment"  
     ng-show="editItem == true && !record.arrival" 
     ng-hide="!editItem">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input placeholder="Add a comment" 
               class="form-control" 
               ng-model="record.comment">  
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row msf-comment-row"  
     ng-show="!editItem && record.comment">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="comment">
            {{record.comment}} - {{record.commenttime}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first button will show the **first row with the input** (comment is added manually)

The second button will **hide the input and display the comment**, as well as adding **commenttime** (commentTime(record)):

```
$scope.commentTime = function (record){
    record.commenttime = moment().format("HH.mm");
    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};
```

The first button will allow to edit this comment, opening the input again and so on.

My problem is as follows: As of now, there's only one comment and one commenttime per record.

How could I manage to **turn comment and commenttime into arrays**?

I would like to add different comments and different commenttime, more like a checkpoint thing.

### EDIT

Following the answer from Spasho I've gotten here:

```
$scope.recordlist = extractRecordJSONFromLocalStorage();

$scope.addRecord = function () {
    $scope.recordlist.push(
            {
                date: $scope.dateJson, 
                time: $scope.time, 
                car: $scope.carList.code, 
                driver: $scope.driverList.name,
                from: $scope.locationList.place,
                destination: $scope.locationList2.place, 
                pax: $scope.paxList,
                comment: [{
                             message: '',
                             commenttime: ''
                         }],
                commenttime: '',
                arrival: '',
                inserted: '',
                cancelled:'',
                duration:''
            }
        );
    $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
    $scope.carList = 0;
    $scope.driverList = 0;
    $scope.locationList = 0;
    $scope.locationList2 = 0;
    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
    $scope.editItem = false;
};


$scope.commentTime = function (record){
    $scope.record.comment.push(
        {
            commenttime : moment().format("HH.mm")
        }
    );
    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};

function jsonToRecordLocalStorage(recordlist) {
    var jsonRecordlist = angular.toJson(recordlist);

    if (jsonRecordlist != 'null') {
        localStorage.setItem("recordspax", jsonRecordlist);
    } else {
        alert("Invalid JSON!");
    }
}
```

But I run into trouble when I try to **record data into comment.message and comment.commenttime**.

This is the relevant Front end part:

```
  <button class="btn-success" 
          ng-click="commentTime(record);">
              <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
  </button>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input placeholder="Add a comment" 
           class="form-control" 
           ng-model="record.comment.message">  
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12" 
       ng-repeat="comment in record.comment">
          <span class="comment">
              {{comment.message}} - {{comment.commenttime}}
          </span>
  </div>
```

The input with ng-model="record.comment.message" is supposed to store/display the comment, and the commentTime(record) function to store the time.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of undefined
```

This is what happens when I trigger commentTime(record) with some text (test) in the input model:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure what specific problem is if you make them arrays?

Comment: recordlist is an array, you cannot access "comment" directly from the array. That's why you pass "record" to the function :) do ```record.comment.push```

Comment: @Sphaso See edit! I've tried with record.comment.push and I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of undefined! : (

Comment: Try to ```console.log(record)``` and see what's happening in the console. Do you actually see data displayed from the array on the page?

Comment: @Sphaso, see edit with screenshot of console. I think I'm both storing the message (input model) and time incorrectly.

Comment: Ah, I see: ```$scope.record.comment.push(``` remove "$scope."

Comment: @Sphaso worked, commenttime is stored! How to also push the ng-model from the input?

Comment: I've updated my answer at point 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change the model to make comment an array of objects, e.g.

   `$scope.recordlist.push(
   {
   date: $scope.dateJson, 
   time: $scope.time, 
   car: $scope.carList.code, 
   driver: $scope.driverList.name,
   from: $scope.locationList.place,
   destination: $scope.locationList2.place, 
   pax: $scope.paxList,
   comments: [{
                message: 'one comment',
                date: new Date()
            }],
   arrival: '',
   inserted: '',
   cancelled:'',
   duration:''
   });`
2. display the comments in an `ng-repeat` and change input bind

`<div class="col-md-12">
        <input placeholder="Add a comment" 
               class="form-control" 
               ng-model="commentMessage">

    </div>`

```
<div class="row msf-comment-row"  
     ng-show="!editItem && record.comment">

    <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="comment in record.comments">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="comment">
            {{comment.message}} - {{comment.date| date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

3. change `commentTime()` accordingly

`$scope.commentTime = function (record){
        record.comment.push(
            {
                message: $scope.commentMessage,
                commenttime : moment().format("HH.mm")
            }
        );
        jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
    };`

Comment: I think you sent me in the right direction but I'm still missing something! Care to check the edit? Thanks!

Comment: Fixed it! Needed to change model to ng-model="record.commentMessage" : )